# laravel injecting 2 different instances for same class

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

In my laravel app, I am having a class, which requires 2 different implementation instances of same type. 
i.e,
I have a controller which uses my repository,

```
    Class MyController
    {
     public __construct(MyRepository $repository)
       {....}
    }
```

Repository I am using

```
Class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository
{
 public __construct(MyDataModel $impl1,MyDataModel $impl2)
 {.....}
}
```

I have an interface `MyDataModel` extended by `MyDataModelImpl1` and `MyDataModelImpl2`

```
Class MyDataModelImpl1 implements MyDataModel
{
}

Class MyDataModelImpl2 implements MyDataModel
{
}
```

How do I inject `MyDataModelImpl1` and `MyDataModelImpl2` into `MyRepositoryImpl`?

Comment: That might be a sign that your class does more that it's supposed to. Injecting two dependencies that use the different implementations of the same contract into the same class sound like bad design. Please post your code.

Comment: what about a repository pattern.?a pattern that operates on multiple implementation of same type..

Comment: As a side note, Laravel's service container offers [Contextual Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#contextual-binding) as a way to specify which implementation you want injected into a class when a certain contract is type hinted. But as you'd expect it allows you to bind one implementation because it's the logical way to do this. So in your case it would be: `$this->app->when('Class3')->needs('Interface1')->give('Implementation1');`.

Comment: I think you might be implementing the repository pattern in a wrong way, that's why I asked if you could please share your code.

Comment: The idea of implementing against an interface is that a class that gets a dependency injected should not care about the specific implementation, just that it obeys the rules specified via the contract (interface). If you're trying to determine which implementation was injected (which you're doing by trying to use two implementations) it means you're breaking that rule.

Comment: Hi @Bogdan thanks for that,, I have added the exact overview of my code...

Comment: I understood that much from he original question :). Provide context by writing an actual world example where you explain what are you implementing, without the need for abstracting class names to `MyDataModelImpl1` and `MyDataModelImpl2`, because so far I still can't understand why you're trying to inject both implementations, since I don't know what those implementations are supposed to be doing. As I stated in my initial comment, your approach looks like code smell to me and I'd like to understand the context so I can try to propose alternatives.